# I fetched data using twitter API and stored it in a csv file in a single row with many columns.Now i'm having trouble fetching it back

Tags: python, csv, twitter, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

This is the code that is giving error that file has ended as it has only one row with multiple columns

```
for row in rows:
    for k in row.items():   
        sentence = k
        blob = TextBlob(sentence)
        print(blob.sentiment)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case, you'll need to provide at least a sample of your data and the full traceback of the exception that you're seeing in order for anyone to be able to help.